# Converting two Numpy data sets into a particularr PyTorch data set

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I want to play around with a neural network that recognizes handwritten numbers. I found some of these on the web which use PyTorch, however they seem to download the data from the MNIST website in a particular format. My data is, however, available as follows:

```
with np.load('prediction-challenge-01-data.npz') as fh:
     data_x = fh['data_x']
     data_y = fh['data_y']
```

Where `data_x` is the training data and `data_y` are the labels of the pictures. I want these data sets to be in the same format as `trainloader` as shown below:

```
trainset = datasets.MNIST('/data/mnist', download=True, train=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

Where `trainloader` already has the training set `data_x` and labels `data_y` together in one set.

Is there any way to do this?

***Edit***: Shapes of `data_x` and `data_y`:

```
In [1]:  data_x.shape
Out[2]: (20000, 1, 28, 28)

In [5]:  data_y.shape
Out[7]: (20000,)
```

Comment: what is the `shape` of  `data_x` and `data_y` loaded from your `.npz` file?

Comment: I've added the shapes as an edit to my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create your own dataset. Just inherit from `torch.utils.data.Dataset` and implement 
`__getitem__` at the very least:
Here is a quick and dirty example to get you going:

```py
class YourOwnDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, input_file_path, transformations) :
        super().__init__()
        self.path = input_file_path
        self.transforms = transformations

        with np.load(self.path) as fh:
            # I assume fh['data_x'] is a list you get the idea  
            self.data = fh['data_x']
            self.labels = fh['data_y']


    # in getitem, we retrieve one item based on the input index
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        data = self.data[index]
        # based on the loss you chose and what you have in mind, 
        # you can transform you label, here I assume they are 
        # integer numbers (like, 1, 3, etc as labels used for classification)
        label = self.labels[index]
        img = convert/reshape your data into img
        img = self.transforms(img)
        return img, labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
```

and you can create your dataset like :

```py
from torchvision import transforms

# add any number of transformations you like, I just added ToTensor()
transformations = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])

trainset = YourOwnDataset('prediction-challenge-01-data.npz', transformations )
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is very helpful! Just as a quick follow up (since I'm new to PyTorch) is there a way straight up to transform PIL images using torchvision transforms? So for example, take a PIL image and noramlize it and convert it to tensor.

Comment: `torchvision`s `trasnforms` does expect a PIL image. So if you have PIL image you are fine. Just use it with transforms. You can do the normalization using the `t ransforms.Normalize`(after you used `ToTensor()`)